# Are questions regarding the software technologies used to build a specific website appropriate for any Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I recently asked the following question on stack overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20085512/what-software-technologies-were-used-to-build-healthcare-gov

Another user commented that this question is not appropriate for **any** Stack Exchange site.  Is such a question indeed not appropriate for any Stack Exchange site?  If so, why?

Comment: In my opinion, your particular question is rather localised, and subject to change. Also (just curious), what did you want to learn from understanding what software technologies were used to build a particular website?

Comment: Support the [healthcare.gov.stackexchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61052/affordable-care-act-obama-care) on Area 51!

Comment: Why would the web server and database technologies matter? There's nothing specific to those that is meaningful, whether it's IIS and SQL Server or Apache and MySQL. There's no indication that the DBMS or web server had any impact on the problems with that site, AFAIK; it seems to be all related to failed implementation and testing.

Comment: Even if implementation is to blame, knowing the technologies used can be helpful. People look at successful websites when choosing technologies for their own sites.  I commonly hear the following, "I want drupal because whitehouse.gov used drupal."  Say healthcare.gov also used drupal.  In this scenario, you could cite the failed implementation of healthcare.gov to highlight the fact that success is NOT necessarily tied to the technology chosen, but rather how it was implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions like this aren't a great fit for the Stack Exchange format mainly because they aren't about a specific programming problem. Also, like questions about design and other decisions ("Why did the designers of x language not implement y feature?") they have the problem that  the only people who can answer it with authority are the system's architects themselves. Any imaginable answer to this question either comes from the architects themselves, or it would essentially be a link pointing to another resource like a newspaper article.

Stack Exchange traditionally isn't a great place for that kind of question. It *would* have a place in chat, definitely.

<sub>Oh, and.... a review of the available literature doesn't reveal what tech stack they were using, but it proves they were smoking plenty of crack. Look at these quotes from [this now hilarious Atlantic article](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/06/healthcaregov-code-developed-by-the-people-and-for-the-people-released-back-to-the-people/277295/):</sub>

> <sub>"It's fast, built in static HTML, completely scalable and secure," said Bryan Sivak, chief technology officer of HHS, in an interview. "It's basically setting up a web server. That's the beauty of it."</sub>
>
> <sub>"You're just using HTML5, CSS, and Javascript, all being done in responsive design. The way it's being built matters. You could in theory do the same with application servers and a CMS, but it would be much more complex. What we're doing here is giving anyone with basic skills to basic changes on the fly. You don't need expensive consultants."</sub>

*What?!?!?!?!?!*

Comment: Obviously this Sivak is a tech recruiter

Comment: http://developmentseed.org/blog/new-healthcare-gov-is-open-and-cms-free/